# Error when restoring SSAS cube: MemberKeyesUnique element at line xxx cannot appear under (...)/Hierarchy

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssas

I'm getting this error when trying to restore an SSAS database from a backup:

> The ddl2:MemberKeysUnique element at line 63, column 4862 (namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2) cannot appear under Load/ObjectDefinition/Dimension/Hierarchies/Hierarchy.

Google hasn't turned up any helpful solutions.  (a lot of people found that installing SP2 made the error go away but this has always previously worked in our environment)

I don't really understand what the error means. Can somebody interpret or suggest a fix?

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm investigating this same issue. As far as I can tell it is because SSAS 2005 pre SP2 does not support the MemberKeysUnique property. This was a bug which was fixed in SP2.

My suggestion then would be to remove this property from the source, re-backup then restore; otherwise, upgrade to SP2 and try restore again.

Cheers

Comment: Jon Galloway states the problem/solution in his blog:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/06/21/sql-server-analysis-services-quot-errors-in-the-metadata-manager-quot-when-restoring-a-backup.aspx

Comment: Yeah I saw the same post during my research. Unfortunately the company I'm working at has blocked the site linked in that page. I don't think SP2 is the answer because this is a process that has only recently stopped working.

Comment: It turns out that one of the AS instances in UAT had been upgraded to SP2 for some unknown reason which was screwing up the restore. It still scares me that the previous release worked in that environment but the current release doesn't.